# Hide price for specific page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found this topic [Hide price for specific category and only specific user role to purchase from that category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713605/hide-price-for-specific-category-and-only-specific-user-role-to-purchase-from-th) in this case, this code hides the price of sample_category category, but on the main page of the store / shop / I see the prices of products from this category, I want to hide the prices of this category also on the page / shop / . How to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_shop()` condition for hiding your prices on the shop page.

Comment: thanks for the answer, sorry I'm not a programmer, how can I use this value correctly in my example?